# Summary function not recognizing object

Tags: r

I'm trying to get summary data from a dataframe called 'Batch1alldat' using the `summary` function. When I try to run

`resg1 <- summary(lm(Batch1alldat ~ Green, AvYield))`

it returns

`Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'AvYield' not found`

I tried `is.data.frame(Batch1alldat$AvYield)` and that returns `FALSE`, but I'm not sure why. I also tried `class(Batch1alldat$AvYield)` which returns as `numeric`.

The packages I have loaded are

```
library("plyr")
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("ggpubr")
library("tidyr")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The dataframe goes in the second parameter to the function after the formula. The formula should just contain column names. So I think you probably mean `resg1 <- summary(lm(AvYield~ Green, Batch1alldat ))`

Comment: If you need summary, why do linear regression? Just do `summary(Batch1adddat)`

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks so much, that was my exact problem. I'm still a bit new to R so I mixed up the order.